# How to add an if statement in an objective function

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I have data (x) that represents some angles that looks like: [20, 30, 48, 46, 50, 70, 100], and a categorical ground truth which has two classes (0 and 1) e.g. [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]. I want to find a threshold that decides when an angle belongs to the class 0 or 1.

I was doing the following:

```
def objective(x, threshold):
  if x > threshold:
    return 1
  else:
    return 0

# curve fit
threshold, _ = curve_fit(objective, x, y)
```

however, this code didn't work and I got this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

it seems that the problem was in having the if statement in the objective function, how could I use optimise to get the best threshold in such a case?

Thanks

Comment: You get this error is either `x` or `threshold` is an array.  The comparison will have multiple True/False values.  `if` requires a simple True/False, hence the "ambiguity" error.  You have to clarify, for yourself (and us) what does `curve_fit` pass to `objective`, and then clarify what that `x>threshold` is supposed to represent.  Did you go back and reread the `curve_fit` docs to clarify what the `objective` function is supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I want to optimise more than just one parameter (including the threshold), so the objective function should do some arithmetic operations on x and then finally adjust the threshold,

def objective(x, a, b):
    k =  a * x + b
        if x > threshold:
           return 1
        else:
            return 0

and so ideally we would like to optimise a, b and threshold.
Is this possible in Scipy?